# TestNg Report Screen Shot

Tags: email, selenium, selenium-webdriver, report, testng

I am using TestNg for reporting purpose and attaching the screen shot as hyper link to the test cases using Reporter.log but as these screen shot file path is my local system folder. how can some one else access the screen shot through the report, When am emailing the report.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in this case the screenshot files sharing is not up to your TestNG implementation. If you were using some [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server like [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/), [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo)  or similar it would be easier. If the

> path is my local system folder

and you are on Windows, you can give other specified [users access](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/share-files-and-folders-over-the-network-from-windows-vista-inside-out) to your folder system.  First make sure the Sharing Wizard is enabled, click the Start button Picture of the Start button, type “folder” in the Search box, and then click Folder Options. Click the View tab. In the Advanced settings box, scroll down the list and make sure the Use Sharing Wizard (Recommended) check box is selected. Then:

1. In Windows Explorer, select the folders or files you want to share. (You can select multiple objects.)
2. In the Command bar, click Share. (Alternatively, right-click, and then click Share.)
3. In the file sharing box, enter the name of the user with whom you want to share files or folders, and then click Add. You can type a name in the box or click the arrow to display a list of available names. Repeat for each person you want to add.
4. For each user, select a permission level.
5. Click *Share*
6. In the final step of the wizard, you can choose tasks to be performed (send email etc.)
7. Click *Done*

Comment: Hi Hina, please remove this *Thanks* comment. The site policy says: Good answers are voted up and rise to the top. The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted".